# change \quote-command to display text in italics

Tags: italic, quoting, csquotes

I'm using `\usepackage{csquotes}` and the commands `blockquote` and `quote`. I'm satisfied with the display of the `blockquote`  but want to change the display of the `quote`  so that the output is shown in italics.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain} 
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot[L]{} % Empty left footer
\fancyfoot[C]{} % Empty center footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Page numbering for right footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header underlines
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove footer underlines
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt} % Customize the height of the header


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}


\begin{document}
In my document I want to have two different kinds of quotes.
\begin{blockquote}
{This is a blockquote which is simply a sentence in quotation marks but otherwise part of the normal text}
\end{blockquote}
And now I have a longer quote which I want to mark as standing out, so I use the quote-environment:
\begin{quote}It followed from the special theory of relativity that mass and energy are both but different manifestations of the same thing — a somewhat unfamiliar conception for the average mind. Furthermore, the equation [...] in which energy is put equal to mass, multiplied by the square of the velocity of light, showed that very small amounts of mass may be converted into a very large amount of energy and vice versa. The mass and energy were in fact equivalent, according to the formula mentioned before. This was demonstrated by Cockcroft and Walton in 1932, experimentally.
\end{quote} 

And after that quote I want to continue with the normal text.
\end{document}
```

My problem is that I do not get the `quote` to be italics. I guess it's about `\renewcommand`, but I cannot figure out how to incorporate something like `textit`in there.

Any help is highly appreciated!

---

The Einstein-quote is taken from [Wikiquotes](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein)

Answer (score 13):

I don't actually think `blockquote` is an *environment*, it's meant to be used as a macro, i.e. `\blockquote{the quote}`.  `csquotes` defines a `displayquote` environment for this sort of thing, and redefining `\mkbegdispquote` to include `\itshape` makes it italic.

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{\itshape}
\begin{document}
In my document I want to have two different kinds of quotes.
\blockquote{This is a blockquote which is simply a sentence in quotation marks but otherwise part of the normal text}
And now I have a longer quote which I want to mark as standing out, so I use the quote-environment:
\begin{displayquote}
It followed from the special theory of relativity that mass and energy are both but different manifestations of the same thing — a somewhat unfamiliar conception for the average mind. Furthermore, the equation [...] in which energy is put equal to mass, multiplied by the square of the velocity of light, showed that very small amounts of mass may be converted into a very large amount of energy and vice versa. The mass and energy were in fact equivalent, according to the formula mentioned before. This was demonstrated by Cockcroft and Walton in 1932, experimentally.
\end{displayquote} 
And after that quote I want to continue with the normal text.
\end{document}
```

You can also use the `\blockquote` command for both quotes. It is designed such that if it a exceeds a given number of lines in length (4 by default) it is typeset as a displayed environment instead. By default the `quote` environment is used, but you can for example use `\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\itshape}` to set all `quote` environments in italics. `\AtBeginEnvironment` is provided by the `etoolbox` package, which is loaded by `csquotes`.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\itshape}
\begin{document}
In my document I want to have two different kinds of quotes.
\blockquote{This is a blockquote which is simply a sentence in quotation marks but otherwise part of the normal text}
And now I have a longer quote which I want to mark as standing out, so I use the quote-environment:
\blockquote{It followed from the special theory of relativity that mass and energy are both but different manifestations of the same thing — a somewhat unfamiliar conception for the average mind. Furthermore, the equation [...] in which energy is put equal to mass, multiplied by the square of the velocity of light, showed that very small amounts of mass may be converted into a very large amount of energy and vice versa. The mass and energy were in fact equivalent, according to the formula mentioned before. This was demonstrated by Cockcroft and Walton in 1932, experimentally.} 
And after that quote I want to continue with the normal text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The environment `quote` is not provided by the `csquotes` package, only `blockquote` is. With that being said, you can create a new environment `itquote` that applies italics to your text.

Note that the use of `fancyhdr` with a KOMA-script class is not recommended.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\newenvironment{itquote}
{\begin{quote}\itshape}
{\end{quote}}


\begin{document}
In my document I want to have two different kinds of quotes.
\blockquote{This is a blockquote which is simply a sentence in quotation marks but otherwise part of the normal text}
And now I have a longer quote which I want to mark as standing out, so I use the quote-environment:
\begin{itquote}It followed from the special theory of relativity that mass and energy are both but different manifestations of the same thing — a somewhat unfamiliar conception for the average mind. Furthermore, the equation [...] in which energy is put equal to mass, multiplied by the square of the velocity of light, showed that very small amounts of mass may be converted into a very large amount of energy and vice versa. The mass and energy were in fact equivalent, according to the formula mentioned before. This was demonstrated by Cockcroft and Walton in 1932, experimentally.
\end{itquote} 

And after that quote I want to continue with the normal text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It worked very fine. I have taken the template from a friend of mine and did not dare to change anything in the header except for adding a few packages (like `tikz`) that I need additionally. But I'll look up better alternatives instead of `fancyhdr`.

Comment: @PikkuKatja Check the [`scrlayer-scrpage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage) package.