# Typesetting chapter, chapter title, quotations, and drop cap

Tags: chapters, csquotes

[image]

Could anyone give a possible way to achieve this?

- Chapter number, followed by chapter title
- Quotations below the chapter title
- Drop cap on the first letter of the paragraph

I'm using standard \documentclass{book}.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You seem to be asking three more or less unrelated questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each question. However, here are some related questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306889/134144, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288551/134144 and especially: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205364/134144

Comment: For the drop cap, you have the `lettrine` package. For the quotation, see  the `epigraph` package. Last, the chapter heading can be done through `titlesec`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Just another quick question:

How to make it appeared like "Chapter 5 | Satan's Strategy" instead of "5 | Satan's Strategy"?

Answer (score 1):

You ask too many questions in one submission. In answer to your quotations question:

```
%\documentclass...
\usepackage{epigraph}
% ...
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\epigraph{The will ...}{Martin Luther}
% ...
\end{document}
```